# How to convert Maven repository dependences to local

Tags: maven, automation, appium

I´m working on a project where the dependencies are downloaded from a common repository through Maven, and they are read only.

The project is automation testing with appium, and in the base class there are before and after methods which close the app, very uncomfortable when debugging, there is no way to disable them. The only way to avoid them is modifying the base class. I know that using bycode I can decompile the base class and I did it. The next step is to convert that code to .java to be able to edit it and use it again in the project.

My problem is that I don´t know how to do it exactly. The rest of the dependencies are needed because they are used too. What do I do to use only the local base class and the rest from the common repository ?

Should I change something in the maven settings.xml ? It is set to connect to the common repository. My POM file is this. I don´t know what to change here either.

I use IntelIJ IDE.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>singulares.qa.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>qa-app-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>


    <groupId>qa.XXXX.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>YYYYY</artifactId>
    <!-- <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>ZZZZ</name>

    <properties>
        <suiteXmlFile></suiteXmlFile>
        <allUSAndEU>true</allUSAndEU>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>

        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

I tried adding the base class to the project structure and different POM.xml setting.

I need step by step to use the local base class please